# How to write an answer and hide key clues and information using the >! spoiler formatting -- Oh and what is rot13 in comments

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I thought it might be useful to ask a question about how to use the spoiler formatting to hopefully prompt a useful answer where someone can explain how to use spoilers when answering questions. I have seen [this meta question about spoilers](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-add-spoilers-to-the-how-to-format-section) and [another about formatting inside the spoiler system](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-to-format-text-inside-spoilers), but was wondering if this would be a useful place to put it all together and guide people to.

We could also add something about rot13 to hide stuff in comments when spoilers can't be used. Any thoughts???

Finally I am very happy for this question to be closed if people don't think it would be useful. - Also happy  for someone else to open a better question.

**partial answer**
Rot13 is a simple completely insecure coding system which is very conveniently handled by sites like [rot13.com](http://rot13.com) - it is helpful to be able to discuss answers to questions in comments without revealing the answer to someone who is taking a casual glance.

Comment: Personally, I detest Rot13 in comments.  If you're reading the comments on an answer, I think it's safe to make the assumption that you've read the answer.  Rot13 unnecessarily obfuscates things.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - the biggest drawback I can see with Rot13 is when on mobile it is a pain to copy and paste into a translation window....   but maybe in comments directly under the question it may be useful?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Hum. From what I've seen, one of your fellow mods has been deleting comments which contain spoilers and advising those commenters to use rot13'ed comments instead.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm not claiming this is a site policy (note the "personally" at the beginning of my comment).  Just my own opinion.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yup, I know. Would be nice to *get* a site policy about this though, so that the mods can act consistently. I've been planning to post a meta about this anyway; will do it as soon as I have time.

Comment: See also: _[How do we deal with coded comments?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4649)_

Comment: Just spell everything backwards. If you don't look hard, you won't see the answer.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The problem is that spoilers exist for a reason, so that you won't accidentally read something you don't want to. The same can happen with comments too.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms - I tried to reply to your comment spelling backwards on a mobile phone - impossible - autocorrect made it very frustrating --- rot13 easier on mobile. (on computer too I find) --- sorry this is just my experience - backwards words is an interesting idea, just doesn't work for me

Comment: @tom ?ugbo gba luJ

Comment: @tox123 haha - but typing into rot13.com on mobile is okayish the right way around... try typing anything on mobile the wrong way around and it is sooooo painful. Nice comment though :-)